# Advantage of Nattable Internal clipboard

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, nattable

What is the use of Internal Clipboard. If I am able to use system clipboard can I ignore Internal clipboard. does Internal clipboard have any advantage over system clipboard.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `InternalCellClipboard` is used to support copy and paste inside a NatTable. It stores the cells and not only the content of the cell. The system clipboard only stores the content as String. So if you really want to copy cells inside a NatTable, you should use the `InternalCellClipboard`. This also enables support for features you know from spreadsheet applications like duplicating etc.

Apart from that, if you are able to support all features you need with the system clipboard, you don't need to use the `InternalCellClipboard`. Probably you then need to implement a dedicated paste command IIRC.